# Alternate German genealogy sources

Tags: germany, sources

I've hit a roadblock, as mentioned [here](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/48/56). I've found German church records from the middle eighteenth century (1760's) that contain info. The location is around Marbach am Nectar (also spelled "Neckar"), Württemberg. However, I can find no older records. For this time period and place, are there any possible alternative sources of information that I should be aware of?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A query on Family Search https://familysearch.org for {Birthplace Marbach am Neckar From 1600 To 1700} appears to generate more than one million results drawn from a record set called *Germany Births and Baptisms, 1558-1898*.

If you add a known surname to the query, you should quickly be able to identify whether this may be useful to you.

Answer (score 3):

[Archion](http://www.archion.de) has lutheran records from Marbach and surrounding parishes that sometimes date back until the 17th century.

See [Landeskirchliches Archiv → Dekanat Marbach](https://www.archion.de/de/browse/?path=121390-486446). All the entries in green are available online.

Ancestry has also the collection [*Württemberg, Germany, Lutheran Baptisms, Marriages, and Burials, 1500–1985*](http://search.ancestry.com/search/db.aspx?dbid=61023).