# Sources of German birth records (outside FamilySearch)

Tags: birth-records, germany

Most of my ancestors are German or Russian and I tend to use FamilySearch a lot. However, about two months ago, the [search stopped working](https://getsatisfaction.com/familysearch/topics/search_doesnt_work-1c54eu) for me and I haven't yet found a fix.

Are there any other online databases of German birth records, preferably free? Most of my researching is specifically in the Wurttemberg and Baden-Wurttemberg from the 17th to 19th century. A more localized database of that area/time frame would also be workable.

Comment: How good is your German? https://familysearch.org/learn/wiki/en/W%C3%BCrttemberg_%E2%80%93_K%C3%B6nigreich_%28kingdom%29 is an obvious starting point; also http://www.cyndislist.com/germany/. And http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/a/1736/104 lifted from an answer to http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/1456/104.

Comment: Also: any overlap with http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/139/104 ?

Comment: It does overlap, but that one doesn't answer my question in that the only answer is "FamilySearch" because that question has different premises than this one. FamilySearch is the problem that caused me to ask this question, if you will, and this question would have a different answer than the other.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's just me and Google translate.

Comment: The two questions theoretically could share the same answers; they only differ because you've excluded FamilySearch from the possible set of answers to this one. In terms of utility to a wider audience, I think it's worth linking the two -- maybe acknowledging the first question in the text of this one?

Comment: The lack of any German is likely to be a issue. Cyndi's list at least points you to some useful glossaries.

Comment: Not an answer (so it's a comment) but I assume you're totally sure javascript (not java) is enabled on all the browsers you've tried for familysearch?  Somebody fixed this problem for Firefox by deleting a profile: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/958793 .

Comment: Yes, JavaScript is enabled. I've reset Firefox to default settings, but the problem persists.

Comment: http://www.germanroots.com/germandata.html might be of use

Comment: Ancestry is now mirroring some the German databases from FamilySearch. Can these be viewed via Ancestry Library Edition? I don't have a World Sub, so I only see names from the hints and search results (location information and dates are masked).

Answer (score 8):

There are online databases, where you can find records of certain cities. They are called "Ortsfamilienbuecher", which means something like "Family records of a city" [1]. These records are mostly digitalized records from the church. Most of them start at about 1900 and might go back to the 16th century, which of course depends on the church records and the age of the town.

There are about 40 cities from Baden-Wurttemberg, so maybe one of them is relevant for you.

[1] http://www.online-ofb.de/

These books and other databases on the same site can be searched from the genealogy.net [meta search](http://meta.genealogy.net/).

Comment: H'm, these OFB's are all user compiled lists, like the IGI, and therefore scarce replacements for the birth records themselves, I think.

Comment: It is true that these lists are no replacement for birth records themselves. But you can get a lot of information without contacting archives, which might be time and money consuming without any actual results. You can see from which archives the lists have been compiled. So, if you need more information or if you want to get a copy of the birth records, you directly know which archive you can contact.

Comment: True, and until archives put their own records on-line, there are no other ways either. I'll expland you answer to include the meta search.

Answer (score 7):

[Archion](http://www.archion.de) has lutheran records from Württemberg. Use either the search option to lookup a specific parish or start browsing at [Landeskirchliches Archiv Kassel](https://www.archion.de/de/browse/?path=121390-48644). All the entries in green are available online.

Ancestry has also the collection [*Württemberg, Germany, Lutheran Baptisms, Marriages, and Burials, 1500–1985*](http://search.ancestry.com/search/db.aspx?dbid=61023).

However, there is *no* online (of offline) collection covering whole modern Germany. Compared to the US you have to do your research on a more local level, with a lot of institutions involved. Most data is stored in local or federal archives or – information covering the time before 1874/1875 when in large parts of the country public registers for birth, wedding and death certificates was established – in church archives or the original parish.

Comment: Is this outside FamilySearch? Don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is NO, meaning that I have never seen any German archive (church or state) that has an online database with birth or baptism records. Most sites have a catalog on-line, but that's about all you can get.

Comment: Archion, http://www.archion.de/, has a large archive.

Comment: That's what they say, but a search for Borgstedt gives 0 results, where FamilySearch gives dozens, for churches that I know to be covered by Archion. So, if someone asks for database, which I interpret as something that can be searched, Archion is not worth it yet.