# European participant lists for the crusades?

Tags: europe

I have been doing some looking around and with many of histories events (Medieval Times in general, Inquisitions, Wars, Fires, Low Literacy, Lack of Printing Press, Plagues, etc) are there any lists anyone is aware of that that exist or are actively being constructed *(even at a country-by-country level)* of the European participants in *any* of the crusades?

I realize as this [Oxford Journal article mentions *(Powers, English Historical Review, 2013)*](http://ehr.oxfordjournals.org/content/128/534/1047.full) that there may be *"Many deeds recorded grants, pledges or leases of property that were directly related to the crusade"*; but I guess I am looking for **compiled lists from these sources** they mention in the article and other sources, even if it is X individual organized by group of 3 to join the campaign of Z.

The reason I ask is primarily out of curiosity at this point but I also have found early references to my last name from around this extended timeframe...

Also at a certain point [records become very scarce](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/48/how-far-back-can-western-european-genealogy-normally-be-traced) for birth records, censuses, church records, etcetera and people who participate in war die in war as well as migrate and it would be some sort of record. That said  I would not expect any record of any one casualty from the Black Plague but even if I am not able to link to them directly them it would give me something to build off.

Comment: http://www.medievalgenealogy.org.uk/index.html and http://www.medievalsoldier.org/search.php are later than the Crusades but might be of interest to you anyway.

Comment: This is a question that may be worth also writing from a non-genealogical perspective and posting at [History SE where there are already 24 crusades questions](http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crusades).  If you decide to do so and uncover information useful to genealogy then please don't hesitate to use that to answer your own question here.

Answer (score 2):

It might be worth checking out prosopographic studies on the crusades and the crusade states, and historians working with [prosopograhy](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosopography). For a start try:

- Jonathan Riley-Smith: The First Crusaders, 1095-1131
- Alan Murray: The Crusader Kingdom of Jerusalem: A Dynastic History, 1099-1125
- Mary Whitby (ed): Byzantines and Crusaders in Non-Greek Sources, 1025-1204
- James Powell: Anatomy of a Crusade, 1213-1221